# Adding Required in Input Tap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I want the form to work with the `required` attribute and I have added the attribute according to the syntax. I can't get it to work.

```
<form action="#" id="contact_form" className="contact_form">
  <input type="text"  ref= "username" id="contact_form_email" className="contact_form_email input_field" placeholder="" required="required" data-error="Email is required."/><br></br>
  <input type="password" ref= "password" id="contact_form_password" className="contact_form_password input_field" placeholder="Password" required="required" data-error="Password is required."/><br></br>
  <button type ="submit"  id="form_submit_button" className="form_submit_button button btn1" onClick={this.addemployee}>Login<span /><span /><span /></button>
  <input type="hidden" ref="hid" value={this.state.counter}></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should show something from your code that better explains your question but I hope this helps.

```
<form> 
   <input type="text" required={true} placeholder="email"/>
   <input type="text" required={true} placeholder="password"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```